# Compare Arrays / Sets in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my usecase a document is worked on by multiple users of a specific group.
The document holds (besides other entries) the two relevant fields for:

- `ownerUID` (String Value - represents the UID of the document owner)
- `members` (Array of Strings - represents the UIDs of all members allowed to work on this document)

I want to ensure (using security rules), that (besides the owner of a document) no member is able to remove another member from the `members` array - except themselves.

To evaluate this I tried using below function in my `Firestore Security Rules`

```
function onlyOwnMemberUIDRemovableOrOwner(){
        return request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerUID ||
               resource.data.members.toSet().difference(request.resource.data.members.toSet()) == request.auth.uid.toSet();
}
```

First statement is pretty obvious and is working fine for other rules in my setup to allow `owners` to modify documents without restrictions:

```
request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerUID
```

The second statement is causing problems for me. The idea was, to evaluate missing values in the `members` field by using the `.difference()` function for `sets` and to compare it with the `set` only containing the own `UID`. Only if the missing `UID` is the own `UID`, the function should return `true`. Unfortunately even when trying to remove the own `UID`, the statement will still return `false`.

```
resource.data.members.toSet().difference(request.resource.data.members.toSet()) == request.auth.uid.toSet()
```

Are you able to tell me what I was doing wrong here?
Do you know a better approach to solve the problem?
Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

1. `toSet()` works on `list` and not on `string`
2. You have to make sure `ownerUID` is not modified

Here is the rule corrected:

```
function onlyOwnMemberUIDRemovableOrOwner(){
  return request.resource.data.ownerUID == resource.data.ownerUID
    && (request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerUID ||
      resource.data.members.toSet().difference(request.resource.data.members.toSet()) == [request.auth.uid].toSet());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)